# adaptive surveying for a maximal income that depends on a parameter

Tags: bayesian, estimation, econometrics, survey, inference

I have a product that I would like to price for the highest income. The income $I$ from this product will depend on the asking price $c$: 
$$ I(c) = N \cdot E(c)$$ 
where $E(c)$ is the expected spending on the product from each individual and $N$ is the population size. Now, pricing for the highest income is the same as pricing for the highest $E(c)$.

Let's suppose that we can trust the individuals in their word that they would buy the product. I would like to conduct a survey in order to estimate $${\rm max}_{c\in\mathbb{R}} E(c)\qquad{\rm and}\qquad{\rm argmax}_{c\in\mathbb{R}} E(c)\,.$$
I envision that a survey would have a single question: "How much would you spend on this product if the unit price is $c$?"

The price $c$ in a question could vary among the sample. It would be beneficial if the $c$ that is asked later in the process of conducting the survey would somehow use the information from the past answers. This is because the surveying costs and the sample size is limited. The question could be repeated with a different parameter $c$ on an individual but just a small (uncertain) number of times.

How would you do this? Would you alter the proposed survey procedure? Given the survey data and an estimate on the optimal price $c$ how would you estimate the confidence interval for the income $I(c)$? Suppose there is another parameter, for example the size $s$ of the product, how would you tackle maximizing $E(c,s)$? Where to look in the literature? What is the field that this problem falls into?

---

*Clarification.* I am interested in the population size of order of magnitude 1 million. Hopefully, I would like to get some info on the best price and a confidence interval from a sample size of around 150.

I have some flexibility in the order of distributing the survey. Most important, first, I ask a question to people not when I like, but when they come to me. Most likely they come to me only once, one by one. When a person comes I can ask questions until they are tired. At that point I could take their address or a cell phone number and try to contact them afterwords with more questions, but some people would certainly ignore the call. I can try contacting them multiple times, until no one answers anymore. So, the order could be like this:

1. contact (I can not choose the order) AABCCCDEE...
2. contact (I can choose whom to call first) ADC..
3. contact (send bulk mail) EA.

There could even be a few rounds, so that after meeting the first 50 persons I start calling them and/or sending mail, then go and meet another 50, call and mail, and so on. I have limited funds. I envision that the price to go and meet a new person (enlarge the sample size) is slightly higher then the price to call or send mail to someone I have met before.

Comment: Suppose there are 3 customers (A,B,C) and you can ask each one twice. In what order you ask them: A,B,C,A,B,C?  Or A,A,B,B,C,C?

Comment: @user31264 Added a clarification in the question.